# gunicorn threads on Heroku

Tags: multithreading, heroku, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy a python web application on Heroku using the following Procfile command:

```
web: gunicorn service:app --log-file=- --workers 1 --threads 4
```

This generates the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 139, in load_class
    mod = import_module('.'.join(components))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 37, in <module>
    """)
RuntimeError:
    You need 'concurrent' installed to use this worker with this python version.
```

**As we do not control the gunicorn installation on Heroku, how do I resolve this dependency issue?**

Oddly, Heroku do not mention gunicorn threads in [their docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn), only workers. Is this related?

Answer (score 9):

Add these lines to your requirements.txt:

```
futures==2.1.6
trollius==1.0.1
```

After pushing these changes to your heroku instance you will be able to run gunicorn with threads.

*concurrent* is a python 3.2 package and is backported to python 2.7 as *future* package. You should either use at least python 3.2 as your runtime or you should add the backported packages to your project requirements.

Comment: trollius is now deprecated fyi.